# "Experiments are in vitro"

Tags: grammar, latin

In most contexts seem to say "*in vitro* experiments".  Would it be grammatically correct to say "an experiment is *in vitro*" or "all the experiments are *in vitro*"?

Comment: So the question is about if it is correct to use the phrase *in vitro* after a form of the verb *to be*, rather than before a noun?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. _In vitro_ functions in English as an adjective, and like most (but not all) adjectives it can be used both attributively and predicatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. I am in the medical field (slanted heavily toward scientific research) and I have seen this mode of usage quite often.

You could say: "All experiments were performed *in vitro*" (you can replace "performed" with "carried out"), which sounds a little better to the ear. But what you wrote is also quite acceptable.

Edit: Thanks to @EdwinAshworth for suggesting I cite an example from the scientific literature.

https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/53/24/5970.full.pdf&q=Carried%20out%20in%20vitro&ved=0CD0QFjAHOBRqFQoTCIHYiaOR_cgCFYUfjgodgUgIEg&usg=AFQjCNFjHsAHAqNpErCA-NqwjmhLUjYoTg&sig2=_pYXfsddMIQxuO5TxEl92g

Specific instance: "... carried out studies *in vitro*...".

Note that this is of the form *(verb) in vitro * which is the usage I suggested as sounding less awkward.

Another more common variant employing this mode of usage is the phrase "cultured in vitro". You can find many examples of this phrase in the literature, but one example is this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9619554

"Embryos cultured in vitro...".

Comment: + 1/2 An example or two from an article, perhaps?